# Overlay SWF file over live stream from Webcam on Red5 Server

Tags: flash, red5

We have a Red5 Server that we use to host a video chat. We are looking for a way to overlay SWF files over the top of a live stream video. For example, we could overlay an SWF animation of snow falling in front of a live stream from a webcam.

Answer (score 0):

This is what Flash come out with. You should using a layer on top of your video, and that layer can play whatever your animation is.

Comment: So are you saying to just overlay the SWF in HTML? So have a div that the webcam stream is loaded into, then overlay another div above that and load the SWF into that? Also, what do you mean "you asked a very general question on a high level"?